# Cannot find namespace 'System.Data.SqlServerCe'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-ce

I did include the `System.Data.SqlServerCe` dll, put `using System.Data.SqlServerCe;` in my code, but when  I open the .NET page I get:

> The type or namespace name 'SqlServerCe' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have nave no idea how to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This can be solved confirming following 2 points:

1. Check whether you already have `System.Data.SqlServerCe` namespace added to
   the **References** folder of your application. If its not there you
   may right click the References folder and select **Add references**
   option. From the popup window go to **.Net tab** and select
   `System.Data.SqlServerCe` from the list and click OK to add the namespace to the
   project.
2. If you are OK with step 1, add `using System.Data.SqlServerCe;` to
   the top of your code behind file which uses the
   System.Data.SqlServerCe namespace.

Comment: If you do not see that Reference in the standard list, browse to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Desktop and select it from there.

Comment: You can also get System.Data.SqlServerCe v4 through the NuGet package "Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact" at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact/

Answer (score 14):

If you have an existing reference to `System.Data.SqlServerCe` yet *you see a **yellow symbol** next to it* then you should:

- Remove the reference by right-clicking it.
- Re-Add the reference.

**To Re-Add:**
Right click the References folder and select Add Reference... option. Go to the Assemblies | Framework option on the left pane, then scroll to `System.Data.SqlServerCe` in the right pane. If it's there, click it then be sure to check the checkbox next to it before clicking OK.

If `System.Data.SqlServerCe` is not in the list then you're going to have to browse for it on your computer. To do that, click the Add Reference... dialog's Browse... button and try looking in this folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL server Compact edition\v3.5\Desktop
```

or

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL server Compact edition\v4.0\Desktop
```

(The v#.# value in the examples above might be different by the time you read this, so navigate first to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL server Compact edition\` then choose the latest version or a specific version if you know what that should be.)

Once you find it by browsing, select the `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` file and OK your way out then try recompiling.

Answer (score 3):

Installing SQL Compact Server and then adding that reverence system.data.SqlServerCe.dll directly from your Microsoft Compact DataBase/ Program folder.

You're missing the dll.

Im sure you already figured this one out though.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `web.config` file for any reference to that, and correct it. It could be an alias you defined wrong.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/937170/759019) might solve your issue.

Comment: How do I add this? I've tried: `<add assembly="System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>` it returns `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version = 3.5.1.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system can not find the file specified.`

Comment: Look at @nvrtheless's answer. Have you added a reference to the dll?

Comment: See -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936355/could-not-load-file-or-assembly . Should solve your problem

Comment: Verify the rest of your web.config file to make sure you are not re-declaring the namespace in a conflicting manner.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty late for answer. But I also faced the same kind of problem.
I am using **Visual Studio 2012** and **Visual Studio 2017** and I found the **System.Data.SqlServerCe** here.
The same directory for both Versions.

I edited @JesiMov Answer.

Right click the **References** folder and select **Add Reference...** option.
Go to the **Assemblies** | **Extensions** option on the left pane, then scroll to System.Data.SqlServerCe in the right pane.

Comment: i didn't find it in my vs 2017 witch .net version you use ?

Answer (score 0):

use  NuGet as simple

NuGet\Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact -Version 4.0.8876.1