# System.Data.SqlServerCe is not found

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to reference System.Data.SqlServerCe but it is not present. When I try to browse and add the file, it is not present anyway. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved confirming following 2 points:

1. Check whether you already have `System.Data.SqlServerCe` namespace added to
   the **References** folder of your application. If its not there you
   may right click the References folder and select **Add references**
   option. From the popup window go to **.Net tab** and select
   `System.Data.SqlServerCe` from the list and click OK to add the namespace to the
   project.
2. If you are OK with step 1, add `using System.Data.SqlServerCe;` to
   the top of your code behind file which uses the
   System.Data.SqlServerCe namespace.

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493674/cannot-find-namespace-system-data-sqlserverce)**