# Could not load assembly 'Microsoft.sqlsever.SqlTDiagM,version=11.0.0.0'

Tags: c#, sql-server

[image]

i want to add Sql sever CE database 4.0 in vs2012 wpf project. when i add from new item it add , when i trying to create a table it shows me following error. i already installed sql sever compact edition 4.0

Comment: There might be some issue with build configuration. I have observed this issue when you are building your application say for x64 platform and imported dll is targeted for different platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i installed sql sever 2012 express edition i got that dll .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [assembly load error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936355/could-not-load-file-or-assembly?rq=1). There might be some system configuration issue . Build your app and see whether the dll is there in the bin directory or not. If not then you need to copy the dll to the bin.

Comment: i check in my pc 10 and 9 version dll present but not 11. where should i download this?