# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have this in my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8096" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".edmx" type="System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
```

It's work fine in my pc but in server host it gives me an error
in :

```
<add assembly="System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
```

> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Check this i guess this will helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/937170/2871356

Comment: No that's not party of my issue, any way thanks :)
my web work fine in my pc and other train asp.net host,
i just get paid host from arvixe.com, and that problem exit