# Could not load file or assembly when generating report

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports, dataset, mscorlib

A first chance exception of type `'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'` occurred in `mscorlib.dll`

> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports
>   for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI

Here is my code:

```
 Dim Creport As New CrystalReport1
        Dset = New DataSet
        Dset = fncDset()
        If Dset.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Creport.SetDataSource(Dset.Tables(0))
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Creport
            CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
        End If
```

Error Occure here `Creport.SetDataSource(Dset.Tables(0))`

Comment: What is the target framework of your application? Is it .NET 4.0?

Comment: Does it say something about not finding crdb_adoplus.dll?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936355/could-not-load-file-or-assembly)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution. Add this to your config file (app.config).

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework, Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```